Handbrake and libdvdcss
I used brew info libdvdcss to find where libdvdcss was installed and I get
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libdvdcss/1.4.3 and I know from a comment on this post
M1 iMac: libdvdcss missing
that I need to copy these files to /usr/local/lib
I did cp -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libdvdcss/1.4.3 /usr/local/lib
but Handbrake is still saying "No Valid Source Found" after scanning a DVD
Is that the correct way to copy files? How do I get Handbrake to recognize libdvdcss?

This site has some clues. It wants to sell you an app, but I think the answer is in there somewhere.

There's a much better tool for ripping DVDs called XLD.  Give that a try...I have always found Handbrake to be at bit too bloated.  It's available in MacPorts or Homebrew

XLD seems to be audio only... is there some button I have to push to switch the interface from cd to dvd?

You could install directly from https://handbrake.fr. The hombebrew issue looks like the porter of hand break has not done it correctly (or has not looked at it for 4 years)  so homebrew needs to fix the bug.

I installed handbrake normally… was adding libdvdcss so that I can access DVDs that I own
